# Testing Resque + Redis in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, redis, resque

I am using Redis + Resque in production and want to test that jobs are getting queued and run properly. I am looking for something like this

```
Resque.jobs(:queue_name).size.should == 0

post :some_action # This action causes a Resque job to be enqueued

# Test Enqueuing
Resque.jobs(:queue_name).size.should == 1
Resque.jobs(:queue_name).last.klass.should == "MyJob"
Resque.jobs(:queue_name).last.args.should == [1, "Arg_2"]
# Test performing
Resque.jobs(:queue_name).perform_all
# test the effect of running the job
```

How do I start Redis + Resque in test environment? I don't people to manually run a redis server all the time. I have tried the solution where you try and run the redis server in `config.before(:suite)` but the redis-server never starts up in time and the Resque complains that it can't connect to Redis.

I have tried using `Resque.inline` but 1) It doesnt let me test that the Job was enqueued 2) It always enqueues the job inside the `:inline` queue (I want to test that the job ends up in the correct queue).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I rely on gems which I include in my project, including Resque and Redis, to be tested by the developers who write them.  As a result, I do not include testing them in my test suite.  For example, when choosing a gem for my application, I look at the gem's documentation to see if TravisCI / Code Climate / etc. statistics are included and if the project is "green."  If it is, I use it.  If it's not, I look for an earlier (e.g. more stable) version, or look for alternatives.  In the case of Resque and Redis for Rails, both of these are well maintained and popular, thus extremely stable.

For my apps, I simply write tests where I present expectations of messages being called to Resque / Redis.  For example:

```
it "should make a call to Resque for #my_job" do
  expect(Resque).to_receive(:enqueue).with(SomeJob, args)

  my_method_which_calls_resque
end
```

Then, assuming that you have a method which you are testing called `my_method_which_calls_resque` that looks something like:

```
def my_method_which_calls_resque
  ...

  Resque.enqueue(SomeJob, args)

  ...
end
```

This test should be successful.

For additional documentation on messages and setting RSpec expectations, see [RelishApp's docs on message expectations.](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message)

Then, if you wish to test your code within the Resque job itself, you can create a RSpec test for your job.  Example:

```
# spec/lib/jobs/some_job_spec.rb

describe Jobs::SomeJob do
  describe "#perform" do
    it "should update someone's account" do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am not trying to test Redis or Resque (I am pretty confident they work), I am trying my application code. I want to test that some action in my application results in a job being queued in Resque with the correct arguments and when the job is run the resulting state (for example updating somebody's account) is also correct.

Comment: Good.  And if you want to test that some action results in a job being queued with arguments, then what I described is exactly what you need to do to test that a job is queued up.  Then test the code *within* the job in a separate unit test. :)